# How to use SaveAs function in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I was trying to implement a javascript into a pdf button.Once you click it, it will allow you to .
I know there are security issues which does not allow you to use this function in pdf. And it requires you to put a SaveAs Javascript to make it trusted Functions in the computer. So i have put following code as a trusted function in my computer.

```
var mySaveAs = app.trustedFunction(
   function(oDoc,cPath,cFlName)
   {
      // Ensure path has trailing "/"
      cPath = cPath.replace(/([^/])$/, "$1/");
      try{
         oDoc.saveAs(cPath + cFlName);
      }catch(e){
         app.alert("Error During Save");
      }
   }
);
```

And i have these codes in my pdf file's button which allows me to saveas another pdf file which name is "123.pdf".

```
var doc = app.activeDocs;
var aMyPath = this.path.split("/");
aMyPath.pop();
var pathname = aMyPath.join("/")
if(typeof(mySaveAs) == "function"){ 
    mySaveAs(doc,pathname,"345.pdf")
}else{
    app.alert("Missing Save Fucntion" + "Please contact forms administrator");
}
```

i don't know why, but it still gives me an error message saying "Error During Save". Does anyone know the reason? Or there's a easier way to use the SaveAs function using JavaScript in Acrobat. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you follow [this tutorial?](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript)

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond that's what I did.

Comment: check the path before saving like `app.alert(cPath + cFlName);` and check if you are able to write there or if the path is good..

Answer (score 1):

`app.activeDocs` is an array of Doc objects. Therefore the variable `doc` (which has not the smartest name, BTW) is an array.

However the save function requires one Doc object to work.

Try whether replacing

```
mySaveAs(doc,pathname,"345.pdf")
```

with

```
mySaveAs(this,pathname,"345.pdf")
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

I've an old code for similar thing, and that used the below code for saving the current file in new folder. I had used this in Adobe 6. Check if this works for you.

```
this.saveAs(destfolder+filename);
```